# Selecting only the first two items from and order

Tags: mysql

I need you help regarding something, i have 3 tables ORDERS, ORDER_ITEM, ORDER_ITEM_LINE.

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(`id` int, `date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO orders
(`id`, `date`)
VALUES
(78, '2017-01-03 00:00:00'),
(79, '2017-02-03 00:00:00'),
(80, '2017-03-03 00:00:00'),
(81, '2017-04-03 00:00:00'),
(82, '2017-05-03 00:00:00'),
(83, '2017-06-03 00:00:00'),
(84, '2017-07-03 00:00:00')
```

;

```
CREATE TABLE order_item
(`id` int, `fk_o_id` int, `sku` int)
;

INSERT INTO order_item
(`id`, `fk_o_id`, `sku`)
VALUES
(10, 78, 123),
(11, 79, 124),
(12, 79, 125),
(13, 80, 126),
(14, 82, 127),
(15, 82, 128),
(16, 82, 129)
;


CREATE TABLE order_item_line
(`id` int, `fk_oi_id` int, `line_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO order_item_line
(`id`, `fk_oi_id`, `line_id`)
VALUES
(33, 10, 1),
(34, 11, 1),
(35, 12, 2),
(36, 13, 1),
(37, 14, 1),
(38, 15, 2),
(39, 16, 3)
```

;

I would like to display all orders with 2 or more than 2 items but only first two so it will be line_id - 1 and 2.

The outcome should look like:

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vMDw.png)

If you have any ideas, thank you in advance.

Comment: show table structure in text format

Comment: Just a moment please

Comment: ok i know that but please give some text format of table instead image format.than i easily do that for you

Comment: I don't know how to format the table in the comment and is really mashed up...

Comment: not in the comment.edit the queation.here you can easily create table http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Could you please try with this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ef185

Comment: thats not possible in mysql..please check again your desire output which you want

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you require, you will need to create another table.  In this example I created a table called TESTQUERY and inserted data to count how many times the orders id appeared

Table creation

```
CREATE TABLE TESTQUERY
(`id` int, `count` int)
```

Data into the test table

```
INSERT INTO TESTQUERY
(
SELECT o.id, COUNT(o.id) as count FROM orders o 
JOIN order_item oi ON oi.fk_o_id = o.id 
JOIN order_item_line oil ON oil.fk_oi_id = oi.id
GROUP BY o.id
)
```

I then queried against all for databases using the query below and it returned your desired outcome

```
SELECT o.id, oi.sku, oil.line_id FROM orders o
JOIN order_item oi ON oi.fk_o_id = o.id
JOIN order_item_line oil ON oil.fk_oi_id = oi.id
JOIN TESTQUERY t ON t.id = o.id
WHERE t.count > 1 AND oil.line_id < 3
```

I hope this helps